# Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to do some coding and I've taken a free webhost for that.

```
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "ltm_23041946";
$password = "pass_wass_heree";
$dbname = "ltm_23041946_a";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Is my code, but I get multiple errors with this. Here are my errors;

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in >/home/vol14_2/ultimatefreehost.in/ltm_23041946/htdocs/create.php on line 12
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: conn in >/home/vol14_2/ultimatefreehost.in/ltm_23041946/htdocs/create.php on line 18
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in >/home/vol14_2/ultimatefreehost.in/ltm_23041946/htdocs/create.php:18 Stack >trace: #0 /home/vol14_2/ultimatefreehost.in/ltm_23041946/htdocs/create.php(51): >insert('a', 'md2') #1 {main} thrown in >/home/vol14_2/ultimatefreehost.in/ltm_23041946/htdocs/create.php on line 18

I searched around trying to get answers, but I am still stuck with this. If anyone could help, I would be thankfull!

Comment: Which is line 18 in this script of 5 lines please?

Comment: The first warning seems to be the cause of the rest of the problems; you don't have a database connection.

Comment: Did you start your MySQL Server? normally connection refused means you didnt, or it failed to start #

Comment: @RiggsFolly `$conn->query($sql);` is line 18

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am using free webhost service of a site. I have created the database + user

Comment: @jeroen Yes, I do get that too. But it isn't my fault, I am using a free webhost service. And I have create the database etc. And some tabels

Comment: @RiggsFolly It does actually, I can make databases in the cpanel, and they also said it "Unlimited Databases"

Comment: Have you checked if the ip of your mysql server is actually localhost or something else? Usually shared hosting providers have a different url / ip for their sql databases.

Comment: try localhost instead of IP.

Answer (score 0):

Even using `127.0.0.1` connection might not work in servers with multiple interfaces or with special routing rules. Run `mysqlcheck --help` and take the IP address and port shown at the bottom in the "port" and "host" fields. For example:

```
port                              3306
host                              192.168.1.23
```

Use the IP and port that MySQL recognizes:

```
$servername = "192.168.1.23:3306";
```